# JSON Encoding and decoding of UTF8 characters in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, json

When decoding/encoding a utf8 string using json_encode/json_decode I do not get back the string in the original encoding...

```
$test = '{"c":"limón"}';

echo $test;                           //=> {"c":"limón"}    
echo json_decode($test)->{"c"};       //=> limón
echo json_encode(json_decode($test)); //=> {"c":"lim\u00f3n"}
```

How can I encode the string back to its original encoding (utf8)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior of `json_encode` is to escape all Unicode characters. If your PHP is version 5.4.0 or greater, you can pass `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as the second parameter of `json_encode` to get the behavior you're expecting. There are numerous hacks to get this behavior in earlier versions, including [preprocessing your object to encode Unicode characters as HTML entities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#105742), then reversing the transformation afterwards.