# Symfony2 - Characters change from my database MySQL in a json response

Tags: mysql, sql, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a web application with Symfony and MySQL as database. My database creation syntax is as below:

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The table which I need to know why is returning unexpected text is:

```
CREATE TABLE `elements` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=132 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And the entity code in PHP is:

```
/**
 * 
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="elements")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Element
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

When the name of the Element has Spanish characters like á,é,í,ó,ú,ñ; in the browser is correctly rendered, and in the database the characters are stored in this way, but when I try to return this information using a JsonResponse, the characters are converted to others codes. For example:

```
$result['id']       = $e->getId();
$result['name']     = $e->getName();

return new JsonResponse( array('response' => $result) );
```

And the response shows:

```
"response":{
    "id":26,
    "name":"Avi\u00f3n"
}
```

And name should be "Avión" instead.

I would like to know why this happens and how can avoid this behavior.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you called new `JsonResponse($data)`, among other things, your data is encoded in this way:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

By default, [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) escapes unicode characters, so the output you get is the expected one. If you don't want to have your unicode escaped, you can create your controller response as follow:

```
$data = array('response' => $result);
return new Response( json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT));
```

Comment: return new JsonResponse(
            json_encode(['message' => 'success','result'=>$result], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT),
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            ['charset'=>'UTF-8','Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=>'*'],
            true); to have headers set content-type application/json and other custom

Answer (score 2):

I don't see actual problem here.

They are **not**  `converted to other codes`.

Instead, they are utf-8 encoded (default JSON encoding).

Some info : [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) section 2.5 strings

\u00F3 is utf-8 encoded character `ó`, see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f3/index.htm)

UPDATE:

Read this : [JSON Encoding and decoding of UTF8 characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864865/json-encoding-and-decoding-of-utf8-characters-in-php)

Comment: Just wanted to add this comment to accomplish your answer: To decode the encoded JSON in client side (e.g. jQuery) he might want to change the headers *Content-Type* to **application/json; charset=utf-8**, because that's what the client side is expecting for. It's always good to make things consistent. Right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @rkosegi. I voted up your answer.

Comment: @Javad, agree with you, by explicitly setting encoding on client side you don;t break anything, but makes think more compliant.